# What are the post parameters i need to pass to the facebook login page?

Tags: facebook, http-post, webautomation

What are the post parameters i need to pass to the facebook login page?

Answer (score 3):

To login to Facebook via http requests you can do this:

make a post request to this url:

```
https://login.facebook.com/login.php
```

make sure you have the following header set:

```
Cookie: reg_fb_gate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; reg_fb_ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F
```

and use these post parameters:

```
locale=en_US&email=email@site.com&pass=password&persistent=1
```

(make sure to set your own email and pass

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't use this method anymore. They even removed all references to it from their docs. Google cache still has them [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sls0m-R6XyoJ:wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorization_and_Authentication_for_Desktop_Applications+facebook+login.php+redirect&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) if you really need those (not sure if that link works for you).

New way of authorization is described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).